# Cannot play youtube video in webview using react-native-webview under EXPO

Tags: webview, expo

I am developing an app using the EXPO platform, this is my code:

```
<WebView
                useWebKit={true}
                style={{width:200, height:200,}}
                scrollEnabled={false}
                domStorageEnabled={true}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                source={{uri:iframeUrl}}
        />
```

I am testing this on a real device (Android), you can clearly see the youtube video screen but on the youtube video screen it keeps saying video unavailable.

this is the iframeUrl im passing as a variable:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/eU4ZvfkmOck?rel=0&autoplay=0&showinfo=0&controls=0
```

I tested this in the browser and i get the same result, the id is correct by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this out.

react-native-youtube-iframe

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-youtube-iframe

```
<YoutubePlayer
  height={200}
  play={playing}
  videoId={<youtube video ID>}
  onChangeState={onStateChange}
/>
```